# Filter report table with a string name value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2016

This is the data set I am trying to filter in Report Builder.
All columns have numerical values(blacked out) except for the first 'name' column.
I want to filter this table based on the row's string value from this 'name' column.

[Complete table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmLME.png)

I have tried to hard-code the 'name' values into the filter within the Tablix properties. I have tried various configurations to get the result of a single row based on the 'name' value (in this example, the first row).

[Report Builder Tablix Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDVeR.png)

Every attempt results with an empty table. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and the advice of other posts have not provided a solution that works for me.

[Empty table :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUUzN.png)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would try `="01. GR PREM PREV YR"`. If that doesn't work, I would check the string for a RETURN or other non-printable character at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This gave me an idea.
I changed the name of the 'name' column to 'CALCULATION' because 'name' is a Keyword in T-SQL. It must have been affecting how report builder maps the string value to the column. Not sure if this was the actual cause, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your columns are not aliased with SQL Keywords.

In this example, name is a SQL keyword. I changed it to [CALCULATION] and the filter worked with the following expression in the tablix properties;

[Corrected Tablix Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z493.png)

Note that the filter works with both having the string value with no quotes nor equal sign in front of the expression, and also works with an equal sign and quotes around the string value.